# Different fnmark style in footer and text

Tags: macros, header-footer, footnotes

I'm using the memoir document class and redefining fnmark like this in my preamble:

```tex
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage[bottom,hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\blueboxedfnmark}[1]{%
  \begingroup%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{2pt}%
  \raisebox{7pt}{\colorbox{blue}{\color{white}{%
    \tiny{#1}%
  }}}
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand{\whiteboxedfnmark}[1]{%
  \begingroup%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{2pt}%
  \raisebox{7pt}{\colorbox{blue}{\color{white}{%
    \tiny{#1}%
  }}}
  \endgroup
}

\makeatletter % boxes footnote number
\renewcommand{\@makefnmark}{\blueboxedfnmark{\@thefnmark}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
this is a footnote\footnote{I'm in the footer} in the document text
\end{document}
```

I'd like footnotes in the footer to always use `blueboxedfnmark`, but footnotes in certain environments to use `whiteboxedfnmark`. Is this possible?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine your `\footnote` command so the marker is printed first in the text in one style via `\footnotemarker`, and the footnote is printed afterwards in the default style via `\footnotetext`.  Using `etoolbox` you can use `\AtBeginEnvironment` to make such a change apply to specific environments.  Here is an example changing the behaviour in `quotations`, with `white` changed to `red` for clarity.

[image: Sample in text]

[image: Sample in foot]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage[bottom,hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\boxedfnmark}[1]{%
  \begingroup%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{2pt}%
  \raisebox{7pt}{\colorbox{fnboxcolour}{\color{fntextcolour}{%
    \tiny{#1}%
  }}}
  \endgroup
}

\colorlet{fnboxcolour}{blue}
\colorlet{fntextcolour}{white}

\makeatletter % boxes footnote number
\renewcommand{\@makefnmark}{\boxedfnmark{\@thefnmark}}
\makeatother

\AtBeginEnvironment{quotation}{%
  \renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{%
  {\colorlet{fnboxcolour}{red}\footnotemark}%
  \footnotetext{#1}}}

\begin{document}

This is a footnote\footnote{I'm in the footer} in the document text.

\begin{quotation}
  This is a footnote\footnote{I'm in the footer} in a quotation.
\end{quotation}

This is another footnote\footnote{I'm in the footer} in the document
text. 

\end{document}
```